# changing java project module hierarchy

Tags: java, project

when I create a new java project in intellij the module is: com.example.ProjectName .
how can I use my own domain?
like:
us.mysite.ProjectName

I've already tried to look for it and didn't found the answer.

Comment: did you try to use refactor option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the name of the java package. In order to change the package, the `package foo.domain.project` line must be changed along with the name of the directory in which the code lies. As seen [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/populating-projects.html) packages can be created with varying names through IntelliJ(including possibly when creating a new project), or a file can change:

```
package foo.domain.project;
```

to

```
package bar.dom.proj;
```

and move sources from the `src/foo/domain/project` directory to the `/bar/dom/proj` directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of useful information available on [**Netbeans refactoring wiki**](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring). Here is how you can rename your package

> Step1 : Right-Click on the package name, in the Refactor menu select
>   Rename (Ctrl+R)
>
> Step2 : In “New Name” enter the new name that you desire for the
>   token. Then click on Refactor button complete the operation.
>   Optionally you preview the effect of the refactoring.